# Search filter in listview for array of strings with android SearchView

Tags: android, listview, filter, searchview, android-search

I need to filter my list items via getFilter method, In my Model class, I have an array variable named `genre`.

This genre sometimes is one word, and sometimes more than one separated with `,` . For example like:

***android, iPhone, blackberry***.

Now in my code when I try to search in my list for an item, it will only search for the first word(***android***). In another word, if I try to search for iPhone, this item will not be shown in my new filtered list.

In below code I know I'm doing it wrong, but can you help me correct it, please?

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            dataList = (List<ProductLocal>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<ProductLocal> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataListFilter.size(); i++) {
                ProductLocal dataNames = dataListFilter.get(i);
                String genreStr = "";
                for (String str : dataNames.getGenre()) {
                    genreStr += str;
                }
                genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
                if (genreStr.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()) ) {
                    filteredList.add(dataNames);
                }
            }
            results.count = filteredList.size();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

And my another question is:

How can I search for items with more than one genre seperatted with `,` ?

For example query = `android,blackberry`

And result comes up with all items that have this two genres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing the strings partially you can use the indexOf function like below.

```
if(dataNames.getGenre().toLowerCase().indexOf(constraint)>-1){
 //add to your list
 filteredList.add(dataNames);
} else{
  //doesn't satisfy the filter condition. 
}
```

Another thing noticed is that if your getGenre() is a List you don't need to add all the string together and check the filter condition you can do it like below.
You can split the comma separated value to a list string and loop through it and check filter.

```
List<String> filterList = Arrays.asList(constraint.split(","))
bool hasAdded;
for (String str : dataNames.getGenre()) 
{
  for (String filter : filterList) {
    if(str.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.trim().toLowerCase())>-1){
    //add to your list
    filteredList.add(dataNames);
    hasAdded = true;
    break;
   }
   if(hasAdded) break;
  }
}
```

Also you can change the for loop with foreach for looping dataListFilter.

Comment: It works for single keyword search but, when I try to do `multi-keyword` search It will duplicate my filtered list and not function for the second keyword.

Comment: If there is space after comma you have to put trim on the filter string

Comment: Still the same, but I'm gonna accept your answer because you already answered my main question, and many thanks.

Comment: I had missed to put toLowerCase after filter.trim() updated it in the answer. Also can you just log the count of filterList to check whether comma separate part is working, as I am not able to find any other flaw in the logic..